# Error when trying to reference a variable/column inside a function

Tags: r

In R, I am trying find the maximum value of a variable in a dataset inside a function but I can't figure out the correct way to reference the variable.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
```

I've written the function as

```
f <- function(var) {
  m <- max(df${{var}})
  if (m == 3) {
    print("It's 3.")
  }
}
```

with the intention to call it like so: `f(a)`

However, when trying the define the function I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
  "f <- function(var) {
  m <- max(df${"
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to use [tidy evaluation syntax, in particular “curly-curly”](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html).

Tidy evaluation only works with specific functions which explicitly support it. To find out whether a function supports tidy evaluation, consult its documentation. But, in particular, *no* base-R function or operator supports it, including `$`.

And while you could redefine `$`, the syntax rules of the R language prohibit `$` from supporting tidy evaluation *even then*, because the right-hand operator of `$` must always be a bare name or a quoted string — nothing else is allowed.

Put differently, you cannot use `$` with variables or parameters. Instead, you can use `[[…]]` subsetting. However, that *also* does not work with the curly-curly syntax. You need to deparse the argument name manually:

```
f <- function(var) {
  var_name <- as.character(substitute(var))
  m <- max(df[[var_name]])
  if (m == 3) {
    print("It's 3.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful explanation. I had tried using the square brackets, but of course did not include the `as.character(substitute(var))` code. Now it runs perfectly! (I will also note that the tidy evaluation syntax does not work with base R functions for the future.)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this.

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)

f <- function(var) {
  m <- max(df[,var])
  if (m == 3) {
    print("It's 3.")
  }
}

f('a')
```

Comment: “Note I used `v` so as not to confuse it with the `var` function.” — I see this advice cropping up increasingly so let me take this opportunity to state that **this is misguided advice!** Name clashes are unavoidable, and R provides ways of dealing with them. Don’t use convoluted/bad variable names just to avoid name clashes. Use *appropriate* names. If they happen to clash, so be it. *This is not a problem!* — As it happens, neither `v` nor `var` are very good names in this case, but then neither is `f` so we don’t know what parameter name would actually be appropriate for OP.

Comment: @zabala Thank you for this. Is there anyway to call the function without having quotes around the variable name?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the thing re name clashes is, there are times when it's fine, and times when it isn't fine (an obvious example would be two functions with the same name). It may be apparent to you which is which, but R can sometimes be surprising, and I don't think I can always tell. I prefer to avoid name clashes as much as possible and not have to think about it, rather than try to anticipate every edge case. I do agree though that the best approach is to use appropriate names, and not generally names like `f` (unless e.g. `f` is the name of a parameter  which takes a function).

Comment: @SamR Two functions with the same name *are also fine*. And, importantly, *this happens all the time*, outside of your control. Name clashes are simply unavoidable. Refusing to acknowledge this is holding you back. Instead, develop strategies to deal with it productively. For example, by keeping scope small, and by avoiding to attach packages nilly-willy and instead qualifying names explicitly. These are tried-and-tested, established best practices in software engineering, and they apply fully to R, even if many R programmers ignore them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is interesting. Isn't your suggestion to avoid attaching packages willy-nilly basically to avoid name clashes? I've suggested to colleagues who clutter up their environment with lots of loaded packages to instead use your `box` package (I like it - it feels clean like Rust). This is getting a bit off-topic for comments to this question - I'll think about it and perhaps ask a different question if I can't find one which discusses this in more detail.

Comment: @SamR Yes that’s fair, in the end we need to avoid name clashes; my contention, then, is that using different names is the wrong strategy. (Incidentally, I definitely recommend using ‘box’ ;-)).